# Correct way to calculate volume of solids of revolution defined by curves

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, solid-of-revolution

When calculating the volume of a solid of revolution defined by curves, I must necessarily consider only the intersections of these curves as the region of integration (i.e all pairs $(x,y)$ simultaneously satisfied by the curves) or is it correct to consider the region bounded by curves?

To further clarify the question, consider the following exercise from a Calculus textbook used at my university:

1. Calculate the volume of the solid generated by the revolution around the axis $y $, from the set of pairs $(x, y) $ such that $ 0≤x≤2, 0≤y≤\dfrac{x^2}{2}+1$ and $y≥x^2-1$.

The figure given in the book (as well as the answer), takes into account the region delimited by these curves:

[Problem Integration Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIkBt.jpg)

I believe that if we consider pairs $(x, y) $ that simultaneously satisfy all the inequalities of the statement, we should exclude the interval $ 0≤x < 1 $, because if $ x = 0 $ for example, not all inequalities would be satisfied simultaneously (we would have $y≥0$ and $y≥-1$).

Also related to this question, there is this other exercise in the book:

2. Calculate the volume of the solid generated by the revolution around the axis $y$, of the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $0≤x≤2, 0≤y≤x^2 $ and $y≥ (x-1)^{1/2}$.

My friend says that all these problems should be considered points that satisfy all the curves simultaneously. Therefore, in problem $2$, the interval $0≤x≤1$ must be excluded (he doesn't agree too with the solution of the first exercise provided by the book, as he assumes that the same interval should be excluded). However, I believe that the problem $2$, the integration region includes the interval $0≤x≤1$. I find it intuitive that the piece of the curve $y = x^2$ in this interval is part of the solid that is obtained when the set is rotated around the y axis.

I appreciate any clarification on these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1: When $x=0$, the second and third inequalities reduce to $0 \le y \le 1$ and $y \ge -1$, which is the same thing as saying just $0 \le y \le 1$, since for these values of $y$ the inequality $y \ge -1$ holds automatically. There's nothing contradictory about that. So the picture is correctly drawn; the region with $0 \le x < 1$ should be included.

Problem 2: I think this problem is unclear and ought to be reformulated in an unambiguous way. If I'm mindreading, I would guess that the intention was that the region $0 \le x < 1$ should be included (why write $0 \le x \le 2$ otherwise?), but on the other hand I would not consider it true that (for example) $(x,y)=(0,0)$ satisfies $y \ge \sqrt{x-1}$, since the right-hand side isn't even defined for $x=0$. So if you're reading it just as it's written, then indeed you need to have $x \ge 1$ in order to satisfy $y \ge \sqrt{x-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I still have questions on question 2. I don't understand how I can't consider the complet set to be rotated around the y axis.

Comment: In the interval $0≤x<1$, a piece of the set is not defined, this is true. But "the other part of the set" is defined (namely, the curve $y=x^2$).

Comment: In my imagination, while $x \in [0,1)$, a solid of revolution is formed by the curve $y=x^2$. After that, when $x \in [1,2]$ , one more part of the solid is generated (which would be another piece of the curve $y=x^2$ and also the curve $y=(x-1)^ {1/2}$)

Comment: I haven't found any other text with a volume problem similar to this one and, for that reason, I'm a little lost on the correct interpretation of the problem.

Comment: As your friend said, the word "and" means that all inequalities must be satisfied, and the last inequality only makes sense for $x \ge 1$, and therefore no points with $x<1$ can be part of the solution set. So (with that interpretation) the region in the $xy$-plane that you are rotating around the $y$-axis is bounded on the left by the line $x=1$, and the solid of revolution that you obtain has a cylindrical hole through it, along that axis. But again, I don't think it's clear from the wording of the problem what interpretation the author actually intended.